# What are the trade offs of limiting relay ports for a TURN server?

Tags: udp, turn, coturn

By default coturn uses the range 49152-65535    UDP as relay ports. Is there any reason to use the full range? Can't one udp handle infinite connections? What's the point of having all of these open? Are there any security risks? Are there any trade offs to using less udp ports?

Answer (score 5):

Coturn uses the 49152-65535 range by default because this is what is specified in [RFC 5766, Section 6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766#section-6.2), which describes how the TURN server should react when it receives an allocation request. This paragraph is of particular interest for your question:

> In all cases, the server SHOULD only allocate ports from the range 49152 - 65535 (the Dynamic and/or Private Port range [[Port-Numbers]](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766#ref-Port-Numbers)), unless the TURN server application knows, through some means not specified here, that other applications running on the same host as the TURN server application will not be impacted by allocating ports outside this range.  This condition can often be satisfied by running the TURN server application on a dedicated machine and/or by arranging that any other applications on the machine allocate ports before the TURN server application starts.  In any case, the TURN server SHOULD NOT allocate ports in the range 0 - 1023 (the Well-Known Port range) to discourage clients from using TURN to run standard services.

The Dynamic and/or Private Port range is described in [RFC 6335, Section 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6335#section-6):

> - the Dynamic Ports, also known as the Private or Ephemeral Ports, from 49152-65535 (never assigned)

So, to try and answer your questions:

- *Is there any reason to use the full range?*
  Yes, if the default range works for you and your application.
- *Can't one udp handle infinite connections?*
  Yes, you could configure coturn to only use one port, as system resources allow, of course.
- *What's the point of having all of these open?*
  It is the default range for dynamically assigned port numbers as defined by the IANA.
- *Are there any security risks?*
  Not beyond any other normal security risk involved with running a service like coturn.
- *Are there any trade offs to using less udp ports?*
  As far as I know, there are not any technical trade offs. I have run coturn with a much smaller range outside of the dynamic range, and it works just fine.

When faced with firewalls or port number restrictions on networks trying to reach a TURN server, a smaller range may be seen as a benefit to some network administrators, but at the same time other administrators may question the use of a port range outside of the IANA-assigned dynamic range. I have encountered both mindsets, and it is not possible to declare one approach as clearly better than the other (when chosing between the default port range or a smaller range). You just have to find what works for you application and usage.

Answer (score 0):

@bradley-t-hughes provides a good answer; to add a point of view on that:

- Defining a default range is a strategy to ensure that applications that are run without customised configuration (hence using default settings) don't clash with each other.
- As for other applications that dynamically allocate UDP ports for real time communications, the configured port range represents an upper limit for concurrent sessions. The smaller the range, the fewer concurrent sessions can be established.
- There are cases where hosts are dedicated to applications like TURN servers, and using wide ranges ensures that the maximum capacity is limited by other factors, like bandwidth or CPU usage.
- If you know in advance that the number of concurrent sessions will be small, e.g. because it's just being used for testing functionality and not to provide a Live service, then you can restrict that range, and leave the other ports available for other applications.

Comment: Does it actually limit the concurrent sessions? Aren't they identified by the client port too?

Comment: actually maybe I've misinterpreted this, are the relay ports where the clients connect or are they for outgoing connections from the TURN server?

Comment: The relay ports are the ones that a TURN server allocates so that che TURN clients can publish them to their remote parties as "relay candidates". The TURN clients connect on the TURN side, while the remote parties will use the relay ports. Each Allocate Request will allocate relay ports that are dedicated to the requesting client, and that will be used by remote parties to exchange packets. e.g. you can have 1000 clients connecting all to port 3478 of a TURN server, each with a different relay port allocated. 1 port on the TURN side, 1000 ports on the relay side.